# Hbase error. org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=10, exceptions

Tags: hbase

I'm working with Hbase and I have started to get an ugly error when I query Hbase.

The problem is when I try to get a connection with Hbase I get this error. The only thing it's that I'm using threads,,, but not too many really.

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=10, exceptions:
Wed Dec 04 16:09:13 CET 2013, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$5@7271601f, java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation@35cc96e8 closed
Wed Dec 04 16:09:14 CET 2013, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$5@7271601f, java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation@35cc96e8 closed
Wed Dec 04 16:09:15 CET 2013, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$5@7271601f, java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation@35cc96e8 closed
Wed Dec 04 16:09:16 CET 2013, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$5@7271601f, java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation@35cc96e8 closed
Wed Dec 04 16:09:18 CET 2013, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$5@7271601f, java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation@35cc96e8 closed
Wed Dec 04 16:09:20 CET 2013, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$5@7271601f, java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation@35cc96e8 closed
Wed Dec 04 16:09:24 CET 2013, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$5@7271601f, java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation@35cc96e8 closed
Wed Dec 04 16:09:28 CET 2013, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$5@7271601f, java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation@35cc96e8 closed
Wed Dec 04 16:09:36 CET 2013, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$5@7271601f, java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation@35cc96e8 closed
Wed Dec 04 16:09:52 CET 2013, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$5@7271601f, java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation@35cc96e8 closed

    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getRegionServerWithRetries(HConnectionManager.java:1345)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.get(HTable.java:706)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTablePool$PooledHTable.get(HTablePool.java:362)
```

I closed the connection some part of the code first time, so next times I tried to get the connection it was closed.

Answer (score 2):

Either your HMaster or region server is not running.  Check your logs.  Can you use `hbase shell` to do a `list` command?

Comment: Yes, I can see the tables and I check the base-master, region-server and zookeeper and all of them are running. As well, I was taking a look all these logs and the only thing that I saw weird it was a log in zookeeper refusing connections, I don't know why. My theory is that some component of them aren't releasing the connection and some time, it can't accept more connections. Anyway, it's just a theory. If I reboot the system it works in the beginning, but when I work for a while, it starts to fail and ager a while it works again,,, a little weird.

Comment: Even when I get this error, I can use base shell and all the command options.

Comment: Is it possible that you are leaking clients, and so zookeeper connections don't get closed?

Comment: What do you mean with leaking clients?

Comment: Imagine a java function that creates a client (using whatever library you've chosen), does some work, then closes the client.  If the work could throw an exception, then it is possible that the line to close the client never runs (if you haven't wrapped it in a `finally` block or similar.)  In this case the reference to the client is lost, and you'd need to wait for the garbage collector to hopefully close it.

Comment: I got it. I'll check the code tomorrow, but, I think that's not the problem. Anyway, I'll take a look tomorrow about that,,, if the methods close all the connections, etc.

Comment: I was checking it, and I didn't really find any error about missed connections.

Answer (score 2):

I closed the connection some part of the code first time, so next times I tried to get the connection it was closed. Thank you everybody,